# Taking a binary input from the user in python for bitwise operations

Tags: python, binary, user-input, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

```
N,M=raw_input().split(' ')
N=int(N,2)
M=int(M,2)
print N|M
```

Code converts initial input to binary and then applies bitwise or. However what I require is a way to receive the initial inputs in binary itself.

If the input is

```
111 101
```

The output given is 7. The output I want is `111|101` which is `111`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format the output back to binary:

```
print format(N|M, 'b')
```

This uses the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to produce a binary string again; the [`'b'` format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) produces a base-2 binary output:

```
>>> format(7, 'b')
'111'
```

If you needed to preserve the original inputs *exactly as typed*, then assign the output of the `int()` calls to new variables:

```
binary1, binary2 = raw_input().split(' ')
N = int(binary1, 2)
M = int(binary2, 2)
print '{}|{} makes {:b}'.format(binary1, binary2, N|M)
```

Here I used the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to produce an output string; the same formatting instructions can be used, within a simple templating framework; the output of `N|M` is slotted into the last `{}` placeholder which formats the value to a binary representation.